# SSRS - How to show date on Horizontal Axis

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I want to put the date on the X (Horizontal-Axis). 
Simple count of sales by day.

Current chart: 
[image]

I see how to turn off the legend.  Might also be good to make bars the same color.  But I don't see what else to do to get the date.  I did try the labels tab, and put in an expression "=Fields!WebOrderDate.Value", but that didn't change anything.

Here are my current settings: 
[image]

My SQL:

```
select CONVERT(date, WebOrderDateTime) as WebOrderDate, 
 Count(*) as Count 
from VendorTrackingViewRpt 
where PONum is not null and WebOrderDateTime is not null 
group by CONVERT(date, WebOrderDateTime)
order by CONVERT(date, WebOrderDateTime)
```

Comment: I don't have SSRS available to me right now, but I think you should put the ```WebOrderDateTime``` under ```Category Groups``` instead of ```Series Groups```.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I thought a date was a series based on some other posts I had read.

Comment: Glad that it worked and glad that my memory served me right. I put my comment as an answer, please mark it since it worked. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have SSRS available to me right now, but I think you should put the WebOrderDateTime under Category Groups instead of Series Groups.